# Umbrella terms for field of vision unawareness blindness spectrum conditions?

Tags: terminology, quantified-self

I would like to know what the name is for the medical condition, whose severity could be categorized by a vision dexterity test possibly related to overall body / hand to object reaction time after hearing a sound, whereby someone may have a low degree of awareness about objects in front of them / in their surroundings. This may be even when the person has perfect vision or does not but wears glasses.

For instance, while in a car or other situation, someone could tell you "look at that (sign or object)", and you would be so slow locating it that it would pass by without you noticing.

I think this condition may be related to either genetics, Down syndrome, or brain damage due to a car accident, or some other factor related to sound and vision processing speed, or brain sensitivity to motion, or both.

I really don't know.

I see this as a form of blindness (because it feels like a (vision loss) blindness, with a lower degree of non-assisted imagination).

Is there an umbrella term for this, quantifiable (meaning that, like astigmatism, you could have a lot of it or a little bit of it)?

What are its subcategories?

Is there an index, to measure brain/eye strain after a "driving exercise or driving video game"?

Thanks.